# How to fix style in innerText

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to highlight code html with prismJS but innertext doesn't take in consideration return on line \n

```
<pre class="language-markup background-code"><code 
[innerText]="getHtmlCode()""></code>
```

i worked with prismjs angular 6

```
getHtmlCode() {
 <ng-container *ngIf="customRow" >
<td></td>
<td colspan="3">custom</td>
<td>row</td>
</ng-container>\n ` : '';
.....
}
```

i have one block of text in one line  but i would looking like in editor

Comment: Not the best way you do it, but can use `<br/>` instead. Also take in consideration using `<pre>` tag.

Comment: Can you try [innerHtml] instead [innerText]?

Comment: yes, but in that case the code doesn't appear anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can't append HTML like `<ng-container *ngIf="customRow" >` because it contains a structural directive ( `*ngIf="customRow"` https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives).

But if I understand your question correct you only want to show a string inside `<code>`, right?

```html
<pre><code>
   {{genHtmlCode()}}
</code></pre>
```

As you already noticed, the function is called only once. To trigger Angular to render autmatically when a change occure, you may want to use getters.

Component.ts>

```
class Whatever {
  get genHtmlCode(){
    return '';
  }
}
```

Component.html>

```
<pre><code>
   {{genHtmlCode}}
</code></pre>
```

Note: You don't need to call getters.

If you want now to set values into this variable you have to create a setter, otherwise it wont set (and the old value remains).

```
set genHtmlCode(value){
  this._genHtmlCode = value;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but <code>   {{getHtmlCode()}} </code> don't consider change of getHtmlCode(). That's why i used [innerText]="getHtmlCode()"

Comment: Ah I see. In that case you should use a getter or put your function inside a member variable:

`get htmlCode(){}` or use
`htmlCode = ()=>{}`

Back in component.html: `{{htmlCode}}` => Note that you dont have to call getters/member variables.

Comment: I don't understand, can u explain me more

Comment: I've udpated my answer.

Comment: i fixed the problem by escape the beginning of the tags with &lt;
                  <pre><code class="language-markup">
            &lt;p class="red">red text &lt;/p>
        </code></pre>